# Botón en HTML pare Refresco de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una duda que no consigo resolver en el código.
Quiero que cuando pulse el boton STOP, se pare un codigo de JS que me está refrescando la pagina cada X segundos.

La parte del código sería la siguiente:

```js
//Mapa X
var Web1 =("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
var Web2 =("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
var Web3 =("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ")

var webs = Array(Web1,Web21,Web24,Web2,Web22,Web25,Web23,Web3,Web4,Web5,Web6,Web7,Web8,Web9,Web10,Web11,Web12,Web13,Web14,Web15,Web16,Web17,Web18,Web19,Web20);
var contador = 0;
var segundos = 7;

function mostrarpagina(pagina){
    document.getElementById('cuerpo1').innerHTML = "<iframe class=\"frames\"src='"+pagina+"'></iframe>"; 
}

function cambiarweb(){
  mostrarpagina(webs[contador]);
  contador++;
  if(contador==webs.length)contador=0;
  setTimeout("cambiarweb()",segundos*1000)
}

cambiarweb();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    http-equiv="content-type">
      <title>XXXXXXXX</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .frames {
        border-style: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        .cuerpo1 {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="bannersup" align="center" style="background-color: black"> 
        <br>
        <input id="clickMe1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="STOP" onclick="QUE SE PARE EL REFRESCO DE LA WEB"/>
        <input id="clickMe2" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="START" onclick="QUE ARRANQUE EL REFRESCO DE LA WEB"/>
        <input id= "clicMe3" type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Go To Web" onClick="location.href='XXXXXXX'" />
        <p align="right" style="color: red">XXXXXXXX</p>
    </div>
<div id="cuerpo1"><br>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>            
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos, un saludo.

Comment: Hola x3k, he leido tu comentario abajo y he eliminado mi respuesta. El problema es que acabo de aclararme la verdad, puedo poner el código y que me eches una mano si quieres, muchas gracias lagun.

Comment: para mencionar a alguien utiliza @ y el nombre completo, si no no llegara notificación. Mete el código completo en la pregunta y elimina la respuesta.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con el código que has puesto en la respuesta. Cuando puedas elimina la respuesta. También he editado mi respuesta añadiendo el Snippet con `setInterval`, como te comentaba te faltaban definir los nombres de las funciones en el `onclick`. Ondo pasa :)

Comment: Kaixo @x3k_js , el boton de STOP funciona perfectamente, pero en cambio el de Start no vuelve al funcionamiento de la página.Gracias por tanta ayuda, soy nuevo en estos mundos, y en el foro, y cometo demasiados fallos, pero muchas gracias.

Comment: Toda la razón, he editado el snippet. Ya que añadí la comprobación para que no se ejecutasen varios intervalos comprobando el `null` era necesario poner `intervalCambiarWeb = null;` despues de realizar el `clearInterval();` en la función de `stopCambiar();`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @x3k_js , eres un genio!! Ahora ya funciona correctamente, eskerrik asko lagun!!! Muchas gracias a todos los que habeis ayudado, gran comunidad de rápida respuesta, gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Si te ha ayudado, marca la respuesta que mas te haya servido como aceptada. Ademas de votar todas las respuestas que te parezcan útiles y de ayuda y creas que son [Una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con tu código podrías hacer que al clickar en ese botón se cambie una variable global en la que puedes guardar si se ha clicado o no. 
Mencionar que es mas limpia la solución propuesta por @Darwin Gonzalez con `clearTimeout()`

```
var stop = false;

function stopCambiar(){
    if(stop){
        stop=false;
    }else{
        stop=true;
    }
}
```

Y despues comprobar antes de hacer el `setTimeout`:

```
if(!stop){
    setTimeout("cambiarweb()",segundos*1000);
}
```

---

### **Alternativa con setInterval**

**¿Por que el cambio de `setTimeout` por `setInterval`?**

Para mi, esta opción sería la mas lógica. Por la misma razón que si tienes una repetitiva y necesitas que se ejecute SIEMPRE la primera vez, usaras `do while` en vez de `while`. Este caso es algo similar, `setTimeout` no esta pensado para hacer un intervalo, pese a que se podría usar como vemos en tu ejemplo.

Podrías cambiar la función recursiva cambiando el `setTimeout` por un `setInterval`:

```
var intervalCambiarWeb;

function cambiarweb(){
    if(intervalCambiarWeb == null){
        intervalCambiarWeb = setInterval(function(){
            mostrarpagina(webs[contador]);
            contador++;
            if(contador==webs.length)contador=0;
        },segundos*1000);
    }
}
```

Y parar el intervalo con `clearInterval()`:

```
function stopCambiar(){
    if(intervalCambiarWeb != null){
        clearInterval(intervalCambiarWeb);
    }
}
```

> **setInterval():** La function que será ejecutada cada `intervaloDeTiempo` milisegundos.

**Edit:** Añadido `if(intervalCambiarWeb == null){...}` para que no se ejecute varias veces si ya se esta ejecutando.

**Snippet con SetInterval:**

```js
//Mapa X
var Web1 =("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
var Web2 =("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
var Web3 =("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ")

var webs = Array(Web1, Web2, Web3);
var contador = 0;
var segundos = 1;
var intervalCambiarWeb;

function mostrarpagina(pagina){
    document.getElementById('cuerpo1').innerHTML = "<iframe class=\"frames\"src='"+pagina+"'></iframe>"; 
}

function cambiarweb(){
  if(intervalCambiarWeb == null){
    intervalCambiarWeb = setInterval(function(){
        mostrarpagina(webs[contador]);
        contador++;
        if(contador==webs.length)contador=0;
    },segundos*1000);
  }
}

function stopCambiar(){
    if(intervalCambiarWeb != null){
        clearInterval(intervalCambiarWeb);
        intervalCambiarWeb = null;
    }
}

cambiarweb();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    http-equiv="content-type">
      <title>XXXXXXXX</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .frames {
        border-style: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        .cuerpo1 {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="bannersup" align="center" style="background-color: black"> 
        <br>
        <input id="clickMe1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="STOP" onclick="stopCambiar();"/>
        <input id="clickMe2" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="START" onclick="cambiarweb();"/>
        <input id= "clicMe3" type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Go To Web" onClick="location.href='XXXXXXX'" />
        <p align="right" style="color: red">XXXXXXXX</p>
    </div>
<div id="cuerpo1"><br>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>            
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías igualar el *setTimeout* a una variable, y después utilizar la función *clearTimeout* para parar la ejecución del mismo. Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
   myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

En el siguiente enlace puedes verlo más claro y es de donde he extraído el ejemplo.[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es guardar la referencia de `setTimeout` y despues utilizar la funcion `clearTimeout` para pararlo cuando hagas click en un boton por ejemplo.

```js
//var webs = Array(Web1,Web21,Web24,Web2,Web22,Web25,Web23,Web3,Web4,Web5,Web6,Web7,Web8,Web9,Web10,Web11,Web12,Web13,Web14,Web15,Web16,Web17,Web18,Web19,Web20);
var contador = 0;
var segundos = 1;
function mostrarpagina(pagina){
  document.getElementById('cuerpo1').innerHTML = "<iframe class=\"frames\"src='"+pagina+"'></iframe>"; 
}

function cambiarweb(){

    //mostrarpagina(webs[contador]);
    //contador++;
    //if(contador==webs.length)contador=0;
    var timeout = setTimeout(cambiarweb,segundos*1000)
    console.log("Cambiando web")
    var btnStop = document.getElementById('clickMe')
    btnStop.onclick = function() {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      console.log("Cambiando web ha sido parado")
    }
}

cambiarweb();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bannersup" align="center">  
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="STOP"/>
     <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="START" onclick="return cambiarweb();"/>

</div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

> He comentado alguna parte de tu codigo.